# JPanel position in a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, layout-manager

With this code I can easily create buttons inside a `JScrollPane`. I used a scroll pane because in the future the buttons will be many.

Now, if there is only a `JPanel` with the buttons, it is displayed in the middle of the scroll pane, instead it should be displayed at the top.

Is it possible to do it?

```
JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

JButton button;
pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

button = new JButton("Button 1");
c.weightx = 0.5;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
pane.add(button, c);

button = new JButton("Button 2");
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 1;
pane.add(button, c);

button = new JButton("Button 3");
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 1;
pane.add(button, c);

button = new JButton("Long-Named Button 4");
c.ipady = 40;     
c.weightx = 0.0;
c.gridwidth = 3;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 2;
pane.add(button, c);

jScrollPane2.setViewportView(pane);
```

[image]

**edited**
based on Hovercraft Full Of Eels reply i created thi code for multiple Jpanels, but the Jpanels are visible horizontally and not vertically:

```
JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

            JButton button;
            pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

            button = new JButton("Button 1");
            c.weightx = 0.5;
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 0;
            pane.add(button, c);

            button = new JButton("Button 2");
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 1;
            pane.add(button, c);

            button = new JButton("Button 3");
            c.gridx = 1;
            c.gridy = 1;
            pane.add(button, c);

            button = new JButton("Long-Named Button 4");
            c.ipady = 40;
            c.weightx = 0.0;
            c.gridwidth = 2;
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 2;
            pane.add(button, c);

        }
        JPanel borderLayoutPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); // wrapper JPanel
        borderLayoutPanel.add(pane, BorderLayout.PAGE_START); // add pane to the top

        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(borderLayoutPanel);
```

[image]

Comment: `c.gridwidth = 3;` What's the logic there? I'd have thought `c.gridwidth = 2;` would be more appropriate. BTW - For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new "wrapper" JPanel, one that uses `BorderLayout`, add your pane to the wrapper JPanel's `BorderLayout.PAGE_START` position, and then add the same wrapper JPanel to the JScrollPane's viewport. For example:

```
JPanel borderLayoutPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); // wrapper JPanel
borderLayoutPanel.add(pane, BorderLayout.PAGE_START); // add pane to the top
jScrollPane2.setViewportView(borderLayoutPanel); // add wrapper to viewport
```

For an example of a working MCVE, please check out:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Foo extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 400;
    private static final int PREF_H = 600;
    private JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    public Foo() {
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Add Panel") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                gridPanel.add(createButtonPanel());
                gridPanel.revalidate();
                gridPanel.repaint();
            }
        }));

        JPanel borderLayoutPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        borderLayoutPanel.add(gridPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(borderLayoutPanel);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(scrollPane);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        pane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));

        JButton button;
        pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;

        button = new JButton("Button 1");
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        pane.add(button, c);

        button = new JButton("Button 2");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        pane.add(button, c);

        button = new JButton("Button 3");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        pane.add(button, c);

        button = new JButton("Long-Named Button 4");
        c.ipady = 40;     
        c.weightx = 0.0;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 2;
        pane.add(button, c);
        return pane;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Foo mainPanel = new Foo();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2847219: as Andrew Thompson suggests, if you're still stuck, then please edit your question and post a valid [mcve], a *small* stand alone program, small enough to fit as code-formatted text in the question, one that compiles, runs and shows us your problem.

Comment: @user2847219: and *what* JPanels? You don't show multiple horizontal JPanels in your posted code. Again a decent MCVE would answer this for us.

Comment: @user2847219: please see edit to my answer for an example of what kind of code we're asking of you, and also to see how to nest JPanels in a JScrollPane.

Comment: I inserted new image

Comment: @user2847219: image? Please read or re-read our comments. No one is asking for an image here.